# Weird cgroups behaviour ( cpu shares

Tags: scheduler, cgroups

I have a cpu hungry process A which is taking too much of cpu load(100%) which causes process B to take not enough cycles...B is related to web response...so when i did a benchmark of web response with both the processes without cgroups, the result was 5 seconds...now when i create two groups and give both the processes equal amount of cpu.shares the time taken increases to 15 seconds.

i am getting good results with a high share ratio of cpu to the process wich has to be given more priority...but really curious about this weird behaviour at default values...

Why would the response time increase with the default share values of 1024 to both the groups, shouldn't it be the same as without cgroups ???

Now when i put both the processes in the same group, the response again goes back to 5 seconds...

Is it something related to the scheduler...

Comment: I think this question could go either to superuser or serverfault... did you write the code for the processes A and B?

Comment: I did not write the code for either processes...rather i'm implementing cgroups for better resource management.

Answer (score 0):

[ If you have cpuacct cgroup mounted with cpu, you can look at the usage numbers to check if both cgroups are getting equal shares. ]

My guess is that your setup has some processes running outside cgroups. When you move some of the processes under cgroups, the ones still outside will get higher cpu shares (in total) than  two cgroups. (Each top-level process gets an equivalent of 1024 shares). To achieve what you want, all processes should be under some cgroup.